# WPF - How do I save a PNG without any alpha channel?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a `BitmapSource`.  I save it to a png like this:

```
PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(myBitmapSource);
enc.Save(fs);
```

How can I save it without any alpha channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FormatConvertedBitmap` to convert to 24 bits per pixel before encoding it:

```
var noAlphaSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap
{
  Source = myBitmapSource,
  DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Rgb24
};

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(noAlphaSource);
enc.Save(fs);
```

Answer (score 1):

A 24bpp bitmap doesn't have an alpha channel.  Supported by the PNG encoder.  Create a WriteableBitmap with PixelFormats.Rgb24.

Comment: I don't have control over the bitmapsource i receive, how can i convert the bitmapsource i receive to one with PixelFormats.Rgb24?