# File size is changed after swapping color values in bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, steganography

I'm playing around with swapping color values of an image, but I seem to have found something I don't quite understand - and I can't seem to find a good read on google on the matter. I can accomplish swapping the colors of an image, but it also alters size of the output file as compared to the size of the input file.

Below is a test class I've written to test the matter, and what it does, to sum it up is:

1. Assign the bitmap to memory.
2. Make an array of RGB values.
3. Split the array of RGB values into three separate arrays (r, g and b).
4. Swap all values in red (r[0] <-> r[1], r[2] <-> r[3] etc.)
5. Join the three arrays and assign to the array of RGB values.
6. Copy back into bitmap.
7. Free the allocated memory.
8. Export the file.

Code is as seen below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GraphTheory
{
    class Test
    {
        public Test(Bitmap bmp)
        {

            #region Assign bitmap to memory

            // Rectangle to hold the bmp.
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            // Lock the bitmap to the rectangle / system memory.
            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

            // Get the adress of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
            byte[] rgb = new byte[bytes];

            // Copy the RGB values of the bitmap into the array.
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgb, 0, bytes);

            #endregion

            #region Split rgb array into three arrays

            // Number of colors in the image.
            int colors = bytes / 3;

            // Declare three arrays to hold the RGB values of the bitmap.
            byte[] r = new byte[colors];
            byte[] g = new byte[colors];
            byte[] b = new byte[colors];

            // Set starting pos of color index.
            int colorIndex = 0;

            // Split the array of RGB values into three seperate arrays.
            for (int i = 0; i < rgb.Length; i += 3)
            {
                int j = i + 1, k = i + 2;

                r[colorIndex] = rgb[k];
                g[colorIndex] = rgb[j];
                b[colorIndex] = rgb[i];

                colorIndex++;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Hide data in the colors of the bitmap

            for (int i = 0; i < colors; i += 2)
            {
                switchBits(ref r[i], ref r[i + 1]);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Join the three arrays into one rgb array

            // Reset color index.
            colorIndex = 0;

            // Replace the values of the rgb array with the values of the r, g and b arrays.
            for (int i = 0; i < rgb.Length; i += 3)
            {
                int j = i + 1, k = i + 2;

                rgb[k] = r[colorIndex];
                rgb[j] = g[colorIndex];
                rgb[i] = b[colorIndex];

                colorIndex++;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Free bitmap from memory and save to file

            // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
            Marshal.Copy(rgb, 0, ptr, bytes);

            // Unlock the bits.
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            // Export the image.
            bmp.Save("../../output.png");

            #endregion
        }

        private void switchBits(ref byte bit1, ref byte bit2)
        {
            byte tmp = bit1;
            bit1 = bit2;
            bit2 = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

I simply don't understand why that would alter the image size of the bitmap, as I am not replacing any color values, merely rearranging them.

Size of input file: [884 KB]

Size of output file: [1335 KB]

No the image does not contain an alpha channel:

```
Image.IsAlphaPixelFormat(image.PixelFormat) == false
```

Comment: What format are the input and output files?

Comment: Both input and output is of the .png format. I'm loading the bitmap as: `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("../../input.png");` and exporting it as `bmp.Save("../../output.png");` @Reti43

Comment: And if you load the input file and instantly save it without modification, will it be the same size as the original?

Comment: Tested positive for 5 different test files of various sizes, so in conclusion: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG uses (lossless) compression. This means that the size of the ouput file will depend on the data you give it. Compression takes advantage of redundancy in the data and by removing it, it can achieve smaller size. Images tend to have a lot of redundancy because neighbour pixels are correlated, i.e., they have similar values. What  happens in your case is your shuffling somewhat interferes with the natural pattern of the image, thus reducing pixel correlations and redudancy. So, when it comes to compressing the data they take up more space.

I wouldn't be surprised if you were to shuffle all components, you'd notice the output size growing even bigger than just shuffling the red alone.

Comment: I did only shuffle the red component though, but I ran some tests on your input and it appeared to be the answer. Thank you for taking the time out to answer my question.

Comment: @MikkelJarlund Ah, yes, my mistake. For a moment I remembered it as if you had switched all components. In which case, I'd expect the size to grow even more. I've edited the answer to reflect that properly. By the way, if an answer has resolved your question, you have the option of [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Done and again thank you. I'm just getting into C# development (4 months in) and this is my first 'big' project, so I'm still scraping my head trying to figure it all out. Hopefully I'll be able to, like you, pass on my knowledge in a few years when I'm a bit more experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Your check for alpha is for the image, not what's being saved. PNG by default will save an alpha.Try this:

[WPF - How do I save a PNG without any alpha channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976723/wpf-how-do-i-save-a-png-without-any-alpha-channel)

Comment: This is why I asked if he loaded and saved the input file without any modification whether the output file would change in size. It was to catch cases where the encoder would try to include more information that the original image had. However, the OP said he noticed no such difference, so I'd expect the size difference to be due to his pixel modifications.